# Can't change my login

Tags: support, login, user-accounts

iirc, I already removed myself from openID a long time ago and have been logged in using a Yahoo account as shown under "My Logins" in my profile here in SE. I want to change to my Google account so I went to "My Logins" and clicked "add more logins" where Google is one of the selections.

Now SE shows in my Google account as an approved app for my account there but only Yahoo shows under "My Logins" here on SE. I'd be nervous about removing that with nothing else showing so why doesn't my Google account show in my profile under "My Logins"?

Comment: Just a wild guess, maybe you created your Yahoo account using your Google account, thus SE identify this as the same thing and not adding it? (since it's duplicate)

Comment: @ShadowWizard Originally I had the Yahoo account so I could use openID.

Comment: So your Google account is totally unrelated to the Yahoo account?

Comment: @ShadowWizard Yes

Comment: On the positive side: all the login / account management code paths get some thorough testing....

Comment: Did you try logging in using your Google account? What happens when you do that? I suspect that after you log in, it will show under your logins

Comment: @ABochur I don't know where to do that.

Comment: Go to the [log in page](https://stackexchange.com/users/login?ssrc=head&returnurl=https%3a%2f%2fstackexchange.com) while in incognito mode, and try logging in using the Google option.

Comment: @ABochur "If you think you already have a Stack Exchange account, and you were just trying to associate a new OpenID with your existing account, you're in the wrong place." -- I presume this means I do have an OpenID account even though it's not obvious to me. One shouldn't have to go through all this.

Comment: @Rob I understand that to mean that the Google account wasn't properly added. I guess you can try adding it again by repeating the steps you mentioned in the OP if that doesn't help, I guess you'll have to wait for the team to answer this question...

Comment: Well, I tried it several times without success so ...